# How to start debugger only when condition is met

Tags: r, debugging, conditional-statements

Assume I have a function which uses a loop over integer `i`. Now something goes wrong and I assume the error happens when `i=5`. Now I can step through every single step (what I did up to now).

But now I read about the `condition` and `text` argument of `browser` and `debug`:

> **text** a text string that can be retrieved when the browser is
>   entered.
>   **condition**  a condition that can be retrieved when the browser
>   is entered.

Is it possible to use the arguments in a way it works as I want?

Here is an example. The debugger / browser should only start after `i=5` is reached:

```
fun <- function(x, y, n) {
  result <- 0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    # browser(condition = (i == 5)) # does not work
    result <- result + i * ( x + y)
  }
  return(result)
}

x <- 2
y <- 3
n <- 10

# debug(fun, condition = (i == 5)) # does not work
debug(fun)
r <- fun(x, y, n)
print(r)
```

The solution

```
if (i == 5) { # inside loop of fun()
  browser()
}
```

is working, but I thougt there might be something better (No extra code inside the function)

Comment: `text` and `condition` are not used to determine **when you enter** debug-mode (browser), but are meant for information **once you do enter**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the argument `expr` in `browser()`:

```
fun <- function(x, y, n) {
  result <- 0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    browser(expr = {i == 5})
    result <- result + i * ( x + y)
  }
  return(result)
}
```

It will then only open the environment where `browser()` was called from if the expression evaluates to `TRUE`.

If you want to use `debug()`:

```
debug(fun, condition = i == 5)
```

and then call the function:

```
fun <- function(x, y, n) {
  result <- 0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    result <- result + i * ( x + y)
  }
  return(result)
}

fun(x, y, n)
```

Comment: Do you know, what the `condition` argument then means?

Comment: In the `Details` section of the documentation it says ''the purpose ...[is] to allow helper programs to insert specific values here"

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to handle that case with `debug()`?

Answer (score 6):

Use advanced features of `trace()`.

First, identify the line of your function to debug, following the help page instructions for the argument `at =`, leading to `at = list(c(3, 4))`

```
> as.list(body(fun))
[[1]]
`{`

[[2]]
result <- 0

[[3]]
for (i in 1:n) {
    result <- result + i * (x + y)
}

[[4]]
return(result)

> as.list(body(fun)[[3]])
[[1]]
`for`

[[2]]
i

[[3]]
1:n

[[4]]
{
    result <- result + i * (x + y)
}
```

Next, specify a conditional break point by providing as the `tracer=` argument an unevaluated expression that invokes the browser when a specific condition is met, `tracer = quote(if (i == 3) browser())`

So

```
> trace(fun, tracer = quote(if (i == 3) browser()), at=list(c(3, 4)), print=FALSE)
[1] "fun"
> r <- fun(x, y, n)
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]> 
debug: {
    result <- result + i * (x + y)
}
Browse[2]>  i
[1] 3
Browse[2]> result
[1] 15
Browse[2]>
```