# Can I set a breakpoint inside an R function to examine variables before the entire function executes?

Tags: r, debugging, breakpoints

I am using Rsudio:Version 1.3.1056
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)

I have a created a subset of climate data in a new .nc file from observed data (Eobs) and I want to use a function within a package I downloaded online (Package:`Phenor` at: https://github.com/bluegreen-labs/phenor). The function I am interested in (`format_eobs`) formats climatological data into a specific format for ingestion into `Phenor`.

I have tried to recreate the dimensions from the original climate observation file in my new .nc file, but I keep getting an error that the 'The selected dataset does not cover your data range!'. I know this to be untrue, as I specifically pulled out a three years of data and then requested two of them back using the `format_eobs` function. I have looked through the function and I can see what it is doing, but what I really need to do is set a breakpoint within the function and then when it hits that, check the values/structures of all the variables/dimensions.
I have looked up online how to do this, but when I type `debug(format_eobs)` nothing happens. I open the code of the function using F2 and try to manually choose a breakpoint, but R is not allowing me to do this. Is what I am suggesting possible? In matlab, a breakpoint can be set in a function and when it is called within the main script, the breakpoint stops execution and allows examination of all the parameters/variables at that point.

Comment: You could include the `browser()` at the point of interest

Comment: I would copy/paste the function definition into a script of your own and try to step through it line-by-line. Namespace issues can make this tricky, but in many cases it works quite well.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/37417395/5784831

Comment: And you can set breakpoints in RStudio https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio...

Comment: @Onyambu you may like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49008890/5784831 ;-)

Comment: @Christoph what do you mean?

Comment: @Onyambu You can run the browser() with an argument to set a condition. In many cases this is very useful, e.g. when you only want to stop a loop at a certain point...

Comment: @Christoph Thanks so much for the input. I already knew that though. I do appreciate.

Comment: `browser()` worked perfectly thank you!